# XBee Network Error

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with the XBee Network Example on the wiki (using ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04 with Series 1 XBees) but I can't get further than setting up the XBees. Has anyone successfully got the example working? I get this error after entering the command

rosrun rosserial_xbee xbee_network.py /dev/ttyS0 1

**RosSerial Xbee Network**

**Contacting Xbees :  ['\x00\x01']**

**Exception in thread Thread-6:**

**Traceback (most recent call last):**

**File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner self.run()**

**File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)**

**File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosserial_python/SerialClient.py", line 426, in run
if self.port.inWaiting() < 1:**

**AttributeError: FakeSerial instance has no attribute 'inWaiting'**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187443/xbee-network-error/) by [cb92](https://answers.ros.org/users/19802/cb92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-07-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-07-22**:
What port is your xbee connected to?

**Comment by [cb92](https://answers.ros.org/users/19802/cb92/) on 2014-07-22**:
/dev/ttyS0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a (mostly) working XBee network going with ROS Hydro. But when I upgraded to Indigo last night, I got this error immediately. I haven't found any solution yet
Edit: I just removed all the ros-indigo-rosserial-* packages, and copied my old rosserial from Hydro to Indigo. Now working fine.

---

Originally posted by [TimboInSpace](https://answers.ros.org/users/11216/timboinspace/) with karma: 141 on 2014-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0